# Limit number of steps to first and last array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of values that can be selected by manipulating slider ui handle or by clicking buttons that increase/decrease value by one step. The problem is when it reaches last/first element, and if by clicking added one more step, the value becomes blank. I am looking for a solution to limit clicks by the number of elements in array or something similar.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4eakah/)

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var sizes = [
        "0 years",
        "1 year",
        "2 years",
        "3 years",
        "4 years",
        "5 years",
        "6 years",
        "7 years"
    ];

    $("#slider-range-max3").slider(
        {
            range: "max",
            min: 0,
            max: sizes.length - 1,
            step: 1,
            create: function(event, ui) {
                $("#sup").val(sizes[0]);
            },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
                $("#sup").text(sizes[ui.value]);
                var value = $(this).val(),
                button = $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    /* update text after jQM refreshes slider */
                    button.text(custom[value]);
                }, 0);
            }
        }
    );

    $("#plus3").click(function () {
        var value = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value");
        var step = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("option", "step");

        $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value + step);
        $("#sup").val(sizes[value+step]).text(sizes[value+step]);
    });

    $("#minus3").click(function () {
        var value = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value")
        var step = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("option", "step");

        $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value - step);
        $("#sup").val(sizes[value-step]).text(sizes[value-step]);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="quote-input" class="slider-input">
    <div id="minus3" class="minus"><span>-</span></div>
    <div id="plus3" class="plus">+</div>
    <input type="text" id="sup" class="slider-value">

    <div id="slider-range-max3" class="slider">
    <span class="ui-slider-handle"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can simply check against array length inside function

```
$("#plus3").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value");
    var step = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("option", "step");

if (value === sizes.length-1)
return;//it bails out here in case


  $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value + step);
  $("#sup").val(sizes[value+step]).text(sizes[value+step]);

  });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4eakah/3/)

Answer (score 1):

some simple `if`'s will work:

```
 $("#plus3").click(function () {

    var value = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value");
    var step = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("option", "step");

    if(value < (sizes.length-1)){
      $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value + step);
      $("#sup").val(sizes[value+step]).text(sizes[value+step]);
    }
  });

  $("#minus3").click(function () {

    var value = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value")
    var step = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("option", "step");

    if(value){
      $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value - step);
      $("#sup").val(sizes[value-step]).text(sizes[value-step]);
    }
  });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4eakah/1/)

Answer (score 0):

just limit it:

```
if(value+step < sizes.length){
 $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value + step);
 $("#sup").val(sizes[value+step]).text(sizes[value+step]);
}


if(value-step > -1){
  $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value - step);
  $("#sup").val(sizes[value-step]).text(sizes[value-step]);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48pbuyyc/)

Answer (score 0):

If you only alter the text inside the slider's change event and not in the button themselves, you don't need any additional checking (the slider won't change to invalid ranges):

```
  var sizes = [ "0 years", "1 year", "2 years", "3 years", "4 years", "5 years", "6 years", "7 years" ];
  var slider = $("#slider-range-max3").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0,
    max: sizes.length - 1,
    step: 1,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#sup").val(sizes[0]);
    },
    slide: updateText,
    change: updateText
  });

  function updateText(event, ui){
        $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
  }

  function Inc(step){
    slider.slider("value", slider.slider("value") + step);
  }

  $("#plus3").click(function () {
    Inc(1);
  });

  $("#minus3").click(function () {
    Inc(-1);
  });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4eakah/6/)

Alternatively or additionally, you could skip using the array and build the text dynamically (with the only exception being the omitting of the trailing s on '1 year' )

*edit*  For completeness sake, an example implementation without the sizes array: https://jsfiddle.net/uq4eakah/7/